# Text Messages & Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms

Is there any way to use text messages to CRUD data in a Rails app? For instance, a user would send a text message to a specific number and the Rails app could use that data in any way. Just wondering if there's a solution out there.

Comment: There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do. Could you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of web services exist to do this. Try out http://twilio.com/.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Twilio! If anyone has any questions about it, feel free to email me jsheehan@twilio.com

Answer (score 0):

my name is Jarod and I work at Twilio.com. It would be very easy to build a Rails app that handles incoming SMS using the Twilio API. Here is a high-level overview of how it would work:

1. [Sign up for twilio](https://www.twilio.com/try-twilio?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon)
2. Point your new Twilio number SMS Url to the Rails controller/action you'd like to invoke.
3. Process the [incoming request](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#synchronous?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) and do something with the data.

**Note:** When Twilio makes the request to your Rails app it will pass [helpful parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) with the request including:

- From: The phone number that sent this message.
- To: The phone number of the recipient.
- Body: The text body of the message. Up to 1600 characters long.
- NumMedia: The number of media items associated with your message
- Some geographic data like City, State, etc.

Here is a simple [Rails app](https://github.com/crabasa/twilio-rails-demo?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) that does just that.

Hope this helps!